# How to run a putty ssh tunneling as Windows service?

Tags: windows, ssh, services, putty, ssh-tunnel

In Windows XP or above, I may run a shell command

```
putty.exe -load ssh_tunnel
```

to start a ssh session configured as ssh tunneling.

I want to ssh tunnel session become available when my computer start without logon to any user session.

Keep the shell command in Windows service seems to be the only solution.  I try create a service:

```
c:\> sc create ssh_tunnel binpath="c:\putty.exe -load ssh_tunnel
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS
```

The service created successfully.  When I start the service:

```
C:\>sc start ssh_tunnel
[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

It doesn't start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows services must be specially written to respond to the Service Manager's control requests. You cannot use any random executable as `binPath`; you'll have to use **[`srvany`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890)** or similar tools.

You should also use the command-line `plink` instead of `putty`, since the latter might not work properly as a service.

Finally, note that PuTTY sessions are per-user, stored in your Windows profile. Services normally run under special accounts, using the `SYSTEM` profile. You'll have to change the service to run under your own account, *or* configure the session in the SYSTEM profile as well (`psexec -dsi putty`).

Comment: Thanks.  I face problems using the srvany in dynamic IP environment and it is not practical to go ahead with the Putty as service solution.  I finally decide to use plink to perform the ssh connection.

Comment: Could you please expand about the solution? I am using plink for the same, but I still get `service not responding to control request`. I receive some `net helpmsg 2186` that is not very helpful.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez: Are you using `plink` through `srvany` or directly?

Comment: @grawity: tested in both ways. I have finally solved it: my `plink.exe` was attemping to run from a network drive. I have moved to `c:\Putty` and now it works OK. Thanks you.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez: Ah, yes, a service would not have access to your network credentials. _(Although it could be configured to run under a specific account, rather than the generic one.)_